# IntelliJ-How to solve this problem about Git is not installed : Cannot invoke(class=Listener, method=beforeTaskStart,topic=ProgressManagerListener)

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

Thank you for come in to my ask :)
I have a problem when I first installed intelliJ and tried to set path to Git executable.
[intelliJ setting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAfWl.png)

**I tried to solve this problem like this

1. remove git and retry to install git for homebrew
2. retry to install git from intelliJ "Download and install"
3. set another path like this "/usr/bin/git" (it has same result too)
   **

but it didn't help so I search in google but there is no about
***"Cannot invoke(class=Listener, method=beforeTaskStart,topic=ProgressManagerListener)"

---

This is my first question so maybe my writing is a little bit poor
I would appreciate it if you could take a good look :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Cannot invoke class error looks like some unhandled exception in the logic that runs git commands. There might be several reasons for that, one of which is actually a corrupted installation.

Please try doing a clean install by downloading dmg from the [web site](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=mac), and make sure to select the one corresponding your system Intel or Apple Silicon.

If this does not help, [IDE logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) might have more details on the exception, and an optimal way would be to report the error and share logs with [IntelliJ Support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/?intellij-idea)

Comment: I really waited to get some help. Thank you for your advice :) I will try and take result , write comment in here

Comment: I solved the problem!! but when I reinstalled intelliJ ultimate version, I got same error but when I installed education version, it works well.